# Why sometimes vertices cant be colored in weight paint mode?

Tags: weight-painting

I brought the view closer to the vertex, I tried to color it from different angles - but it does not stain in any way.

I occasionally encounter the fact that some vertices do not want to be colored. It often happens that these are highley distorted vertices, but ordinary ones also do not react. What is the problem, how to solve it?  '

My brush settings.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This accident can happen, expecially when some vertices are hidden under the surface of the mesh.

There are a couple of ways to solve:

One is what I call the "nuclear weapon" of weight painting: in edit mode select all and only the area you want to paint on, in weight paint mode activate the vertex selection masking button, change the tool settings turning off "front faces only" and expecially changing the falloff from "Sphere" to "Projected".

In this way any vertex which is under the cursor circle (in a view-related 2D projected fashion) will be affected.

[image]

If this doesn't solve the problem, the only way is to manually assign weight in edit mode, using the assign button or the buttons in the vertex weight tab, which work from active (last selected) vertex to selected vertices: the "Copy" button will copy from active to all selected vertices all the weight assignements, while the folder button will copy only the value of the corresponding vertex group.

Be aware that this latter button will not create weights from zero, it will only influence vertices which already have some weight.

[image]

A third method is to separate in edit mode the problematic area (Shortcut P), weight paint it and then rejoin (Ctrl J).

Answer (score 0):

For those using Mirror modifier, what allowed me to paint on the previously unreachable vertex was unchecking the merge button (*Object Properties > Mirror*) or changing the *Merge Clipping* value until you can finally paint on that vertex.