# Weight painting acting weird on certian faces

Tags: modeling, weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

I tried editing weigth painting but when I got to a certain place, the weight doesn't seem to affect that spot. I tried using the blur tool, it just expands that spot more. Lots of help are appreicated, thank you! (I also turned on auto-normalize)
[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247416/why-sometimes-vertices-cant-be-colored-in-weight-paint-mode/247421#247421

Comment: Check normals and double vertices also.

Comment: I already did, it looks fine to me